# How do I remove an app installed if the buttons in "Manage Applications" are locked and can't be pressed?

Tags: applications, uninstallation

I didn't download the application from Google Play and got the apk from a website and installed it on my tablet. But the app wasn't the one I needed and it was just making offers for me to get other apps.

Now I want to uninstall it but in "Manage Applications " all the buttons there are locked and can't be pressed, including the uninstall and move to SD card.

What do I do to get rid of it? It's taking up space on my internal memory.

Comment: Then install an [uninstaller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.uninstaller&hl=en)?

Comment: Could it be the app registered with the *Device Administrator*? As you didn't offer a link or even name to the app in question, we cannot check that. But you could take a look into *Settings->Security->Device Administrator*. If it's in there, remove it here first. Then you should be able to uninstall it.

Comment: Thank you, Izzy! I did as you told me and it worked, I got to uninstall the app.  Many thanks!

Comment: Glad to read! As this was the solution to your issue, I made it an answer. If you please "accept" this (by clicking the "checkmark" next to it), other users with similar problems can see here's a solution to the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Some apps register with the "Device Administrator" to avoid accidental/unwanted de-installation (e.g. child-protecting apps, so the child does not simply uninstall it -- also stuff which implements additional "rules", such as MS Exchange related apps). In this case, you need to remove them from the "Device Administrator" first:

Go to *Settings→Security→Device Administrator* and check if the app is listed there. If so, remove it from here. Now you should be able to uninstall the app.