# How do I uninstall the LINE app (third party app)?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, uninstallation, line

At my sister's suggestion, I installed the [LINE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.naver.line.android) app in my Galaxy S3. After a while I decided I didn't like it, so I want to uninstall it. Weirdly, when I open Settings > Application manager, there is no option to remove application, only "Uninstall update", which restore an earlier version of the app. The same situation when I open Google Play, the "Uninstall" button only uninstall the updates and restore an earlier version. Same luck with trying [an uninstaller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.uninstaller&hl=en) . I also read that some application may [prevent uninstallation](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42427/how-do-i-remove-an-app-installed-if-the-buttons-in-manage-applications-are-loc/42438) by setting itself as Device Administrator, but I check my Device Administrators and LINE isn't listed.

I only observed this behaviour before for system apps or apps that got installed by my carrier, but LINE certainly isn't such app, I installed it myself. How could they have uninstall restriction, and how can I uninstall it?

Comment: Is your phone rooted?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like 'Line' has been converted to a system app. You can convert it back to a user app and uninstall it if you have root permissions by using apps like [App Uninstaller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.uninstaller&hl=en) or [System App Remover](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jumobile.manager.systemapp).

Otherwise you can disable it after uninstalling updates. "Disable" button can be found besides the "Force Stop" button under Settings → Apps → [offending app]

Else restore your phone (preferably from a Nandroid backup if you're rooted with a custom recovery). Even a factory reset *might* work.

Comment: Just to clear your doubt: factory reset doesn't delete a system app. If the Line app is a system app, it would not be affected by factory reset, other than any updates that it may have received after the last reset.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set this application as the default SMS client, given it notification access or administrative rights? I'd suggest look into those issues as it may (although the it should not be) a factor in the issue.

If none of the above are mentioned, and you're only able to uninstall updates, try disabling, deleting set directory then uninstalling. It should remove any files that Line uses to store info.

I'd comment, but alas not enough rep.

Answer (score 0):

Diagnosis: Very rarely (but it DOES) a 'placeholder' version of an app is built in a ROM and cannot be uninstalled regardless of updating. If LINE is not set as Device Administrator, then the only possibility for this case is that it's a system app.
Solution: To uninstall it, you need either root access or a custom recovery. If you have root, you can use an app like [System App Remover](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=zsj.android.systemappremover) to force remove it, or simply delete it's file from `/system/app` using [Root Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.rootexplorer). After a reboot LINE should be gone.